# Why getting exception parameter is no valid when trying to load a bitmap image to pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I'm using a debug with a break point on the line:

```
pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = bitmap));
```

when it's trying to execute this line then it's throwing the exception error.
and when I put the mouse over the bitmap on this line, I don't see any problems with it.

I tried to change the pictureBox1 size and size mode too, but it didn't change anything.

The exception message:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The method:

```
private void DisplayFrameInPictureBox(Mat frame)
{
    // Create a copy of the Mat frame
    using (var frameCopy = new Mat())
    {
        frame.CopyTo(frameCopy);

        // Convert Mat copy to Bitmap
        using (var bitmap = frameCopy.ToBitmap())
        {
            // Display the bitmap in the PictureBox
            if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = bitmap));
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a local variable rather than the subject of the `using` statement:

```cs
using (var bitmap = frameCopy.ToBitmap())
{
    // Display the bitmap in the PictureBox
    if (pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var bmp = bitmap;

        pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = bmp));
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
}
```